# write a list to a file elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm unable to write a list to a file in elixir. If I try to write the whole list I get an error, if I try to enumerate over the list I get an error. it's a list of integers.

```
{:ok, file} = File.open "loop_issues.csv", [:write]
for item <- find_common_items(list_one, list_two) do
  IO.write(file, item <> ",")
end    
File.close file
```

Here's an example of the IEX readout from the module, and me playing with it.

```
commons
 [6579, 9397]
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    (autoupgrader_phx) lib/modules/tree_validator.ex:30: anonymous fn/3 in TreeV
alidator.check_all_users/0
              (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1755: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
    (autoupgrader_phx) lib/modules/tree_validator.ex:29: anonymous fn/3 in TreeV
alidator.check_all_users/0
              (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1755: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
    (autoupgrader_phx) lib/modules/tree_validator.ex:14:
```

Here's where I was messing with it to test it:

```
iex(2)> {:ok, file} = File.open "test_file.txt", [:write]
{:ok, #PID<0.469.0>}

iex(3)> whatever = [123, 234, 6324]
[123, 234, 6324]

iex(4)> IO.write(file, whatever)
** (ErlangError) erlang error: :no_translation
    (stdlib) :io.put_chars(#PID<0.469.0>, :unicode, [123, 234, 6324])
```

And in a loop instead, I also tried Enum.reduce:

```
iex(4)> for thing <- whatever, do: IO.write(file, thing)
** (ErlangError) erlang error: :terminated
    (stdlib) :io.put_chars(#PID<0.469.0>, :unicode, "123")
```

What am I doing wrong. I also tried binwrite but that gave the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`IO.write/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#write/2) expects an argument to be a `chardata | String.Chars.t`. Internally it calls Erlang’s [`:io.put_chars/2`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.4.5/lib/elixir/lib/io.ex#L159).

There is no magic conversion of the list `[1]` to chardata `"[1]"`, the list is treated as a list of chars and `[123, 234]` is an invalid unicode sequence. Look:

```
iex> IO.write(file, [65, 66, 67])
:ok
```

And what you get in the file is `ABC` because `65` is the unicode/ascii value for `A`.

Turning back to how to spit the list of integers out: you should convert the input to something that implements [`String.Chars`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.Chars.html#content) protocol:

```
iex> IO.write(file, inspect(whatever))
:ok
```

And in the file itself you’ll get:

```
[123, 234, 6324]
```